# Smallest multiple of 1:20 - How can I make it quicker?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the smallest number that is evenly divisible 1:20. 
I created a function and this is what I have:

```
smallestN<- function(a,b) {
  i<- 1
  repeat {
     if (all(i%%a:b == 0)) {
      break
    } else {
      i<-i+1
    }
  }
  return(i)
}
```

It works fine great for small intervals, but for 1:20 it takes a long time. 
How can I improve my code to make it quicker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're after the [Least Common Multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). There are a few ways to calculate this, but to start you off you can look at the `numbers` package

```
library(numbers)

mLCM(1:20)
# [1] 232792560
```

There will be faster implementations that make use of `C/C++`, but for the `1:20` scenario this is quick.

Comment: Thank you! Much simpler.

Comment: @ana.la - you're welcome. If this answers your question you can/should press the 'tick' under the voting arrows to accept the answer.